# How to refactoring different actions on files inside subfolders

Tags: python, file, directory, higher-order-functions

I am trying to functionalize and clean up file organization scripts. Each one is something like this:

```
for dir_level in dirs: 
    dates = glob.glob(dir_level)
    for date in dates: 
        files = glob.glob(date)
        for file in files: 
            # do_stuff
```

What is a clean way to have the same directory crawl logic (with variable number of depth levels) but arbitrary actions to be done on that folder level?

Comment: Sorry about the initial comment. On a closer read, this is well enough defined and topical enough for Stack Overflow. There might be a close enough duplicate, but I couldn't easily find something that looked right.

Answer (score 1):

Write functions to represent the "do stuff" part:

```
def example_action(filename):
    print(filename, 'is an interesting file that is worthy of consideration.')
```

Then use a single function to represent the traversal, and pass one of the other functions as a *higher-order function*:

```
def on_each_file(dirs, action):
    for dir_level in dirs: 
        dates = glob.glob(dir_level)
        for date in dates: 
            files = glob.glob(date)
            for file in files: 
                action(file)

on_each_file(my_dirs, example_action)
```